# ZF2 tableGateway select

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I started with the ZendSkeletonApplication and added a model extending  Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway.
I have the following method:

```
public function findByType($type) {
    $rowset = $this->select('type' => $type);
    return $rowset;
}
```

This works, but now if i do this:

```
$foo = $table->findBytype('foo');
$bar = $table->findBytype('bar');
```

the first one works, the query it executes is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'type' = 'foo'
```

The second one however executes the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'type' = 'foo' AND 'type' = 'bar'
```

is this expected behavior?
If so how can i have the second time i call the method execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'type' = 'bar'
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Turns out it was just a minor bug in the zf2 beta3 that has allready been fixed in the latest github version.

Answer (score 8):

Should use select in tableGateway like this:

```
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
$select->where(array('type' => 'foo'))
    ->where(array('type' => 'bar'));
$rowset = $this->selectWith($select);
```

select() will be reset the where() paramters when you call it next time.

See more usage in my blog:
http://avnpc.com/pages/advanced-database-select-usage-in-zf2

Comment: Is there an english version of your blog? The snippets are well done, but I get everything in chinese and google tries to translate it in german, that's kind of a funny experience ;-)