# Set Parameter with TableGateway Select Function show error undefined variable

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i create a function in my model like :

```
public function getAllMenuByOnlyActionPage($actionlot){

            $act  = trim($actionlot);
            $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
                        $select->where(array('status != ?' => 13))
                        ->where(array('action' => $act))
                        ->order('id ASC');
                    }); 
            $results = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
            return $results;

        }
```

When i try to execute then its show me `Notice: Undefined variable: act`. I already see this link [ZF2 tableGateway select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297447/zf2-tablegateway-select) but i want to set parameter for this function. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
$result = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($act)  {
                        $select->where(array('status != ?' => 13))
                        ->where(array('action' => $act))
                        ->order('id ASC');
                    });
```

Comment: thanks it works if you have this reference link please give me the links.